# spring data redis query method

Tags: spring, redis

I'm using spring data redis with query methods using @EnableRepositories. I have entity with @RedisHashAnnotation and @Indexed field. And I have spring data repository to work with it. All works fine: crud operations, keys for index are creating in redis, but if I add query method to repository it throws abstract method error, for example for method findByIp(String ip) (ip is property of persisted in redis entity.

Comment: can you please add the java, spring and spring-data-commons version in use.

Comment: java 8, spring-data-rest-webmvc 2.4, spring data redis 1.7.1 in project and no spring-data-commons

Comment: do you have a gist / repo I can have a look at? the Stacktrace would  probably help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Wich version of Redis server you have installed?
Redis Repositories requires at least Redis Server version 2.8.0.

[Spring Data Redis Repositories docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories)

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all just had incompatible versions of spring data jpa and spring data commons because  of transitive dependencies from submodule.